# What does 'Wie warum' translates to in English, precisely, when you are having a conversation?

Tags: translation, colloquial

I asked a German *Warum?* and he replied back *Wie warum?!* .

I do not know what it means when you put both *Wie* and *Warum* together. 
Google Translate says it means *like why*.

What would you have said in English instead of saying *Wie warum* in German?

Comment: dot_Sp0T suggests "What do you mean, Why?" This is correct, but perhaps closer in tone is "Why what?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well you were asking *Why?* and they answered basically *What do you mean, Why?'*

The phrase *Wie Warum?* implies that from their point of view the question does not make sense / is superfluous as it should be clear why (or *Warum*) something is or has happened.

---

Another case of *Wie* in a response (thanks for the reminder @Giorgio)

If you say, e.g. *Mein Computer ist kaputt.*, someone might answer *Wie(,) kaputt?. This can either mean *Was ist kaputt?* (What's wrong/defective) or as well *Was meinst du mit 'kaputt'?* (similar to the case above).

Comment: Spot on. That's exactly what it is

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but I hear _wie_ used in this sense very often when replying to a question or statement that is unexpected. E.g.: "Mein Rechner ist kaputt." "Wie kaputt?"

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's one of the *Eigenheiten* (peculiarities) of German. Also this is very colloquial language, you might find it in novels but certainly not in more demanding texts.

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of "Wie warum?" is, "How is it a 'why'?"

A more idiomatic translation is "Why do you ask?"

The implication is that the answer is obvious and the question redundant.